# How to output integers in an integer/float matrix without the '.' after the integer

Tags: python-3.x

I want the user to be able to input a 3x3 matrix with each element in the row separated by a white space and each column separated with a new-line. Is there a way to get my desired output as shown in the code below?

```
def get_matrix():
    n, m = 3,3
    matrix = np.array([input().strip().split() for i in range(n)], float)
    print(matrix)

>>> 1.2 1 2
    4.2 2 1
    1 2 3

Output:
[[1.2 1.  2. ]
 [4.2 2.  1. ]
 [1.  2.  3. ]]

Desired Output:
 [[1.2 1  2 ]
 [4.2  2  1 ]
 [1    2  3 ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your matrix is derived from a numpy array. Elements of a numpy array all have the same type.

Probably the easiest way is to convert it to a string first, and then do some replacements.

```
>>> matrix = [[1.2, 1.,  2. ], [4.2, 2.,  1. ], [1.,  2., 3.]]
>>> print(str(matrix).replace('.0', '').replace('],', ']\n'))
[[1.2, 1, 2]
 [4.2, 2, 1]
 [1, 2, 3]]
>>>
```